# Can't set headers after they are sent. in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-headers, jsonresponse

> I am not getting why error **Can't set headers after they are sent.** pops up.
>   Here is my error.

```
   _http_outgoing.js:494
        throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\trraks\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\trraks\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\trraks\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\trraks\app\routes\api.js:58:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:475:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:846:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:828:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I am trying to send OTP on user mobile number here is all declaration for that

```
var code = user.CODE;
var msg =urlencode("Dear User,\nVerify your mobile number.\nYour verification code is "+ code);
var number=user.MOBILENO;
var data ='username='+username+'&hash='+hash+'&sender='+sender+'&numbers='+number+'&message='+msg
                var options = {
                host: 'api.textlocal.in',
                path: '/send?'+data
                };

                    callback = function(response) 
                    {

                          response.on('data', function (chunk) 
                          {
                                res.json({ success: true, messege: "Messege send on given number"});

                          });

                    }
```

after running code 1st time everything works properly but for the 2nd time, it shows above mentioned error.

> *http.request(options, callback).end();*

above line sends the msg.

```
Verifyotp.GetMobileNumber(user.MOBILENO,function(err,mobexits){
                            if (!mobexits) {
                                // new number with new OTP
                                    user.save(function(err){
                                    if(err){
                                        // console.log(err);
                                        res.json({success:false, messege:"Something went wrong while trying to send otp"});
                                    }else{

                                        res.json({success:true, messege: "OTP sent on given mobile number new"});
                                        http.request(options, callback).end();
                                    }
                                })
                            }else{
                                // updating new OTP on old number
                                Verifyotp.UpdateOtp(user.MOBILENO,user.CODE,function(err,update){
                                    if (!update) {
                                        res.json({success:false, messege: "something went wrong while sending OTP"})
                                    }else{
                                        res.json({success:true, messege: "OTP sent on given mobile number updated"});
                                        http.request(options, callback).end();

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
```

Here is my mongooseSchema :

```
var User =  module.exports = mongoose.model('verifydata',UserSchema);

module.exports.GetMobileNumber = function(mobileno,callback){
    const query={MOBILENO:mobileno};
    User.findOne(query,callback);
}

module.exports.UpdateOtp = function(mobilenumber,code,callback){
    const query = {MOBILENO: mobilenumber};
User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { CODE: code }, callback);
}
```

Help me friends... i tried everythig but nothing worked.
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer, I haven't examined your code thoroughly, one suggestion I found is, in an ideal case you do not use "res.send" or related ones multiple times in a function. The error is usually thrown when you try to send response more than once. So to be on the safer side try using res only once, or at most twice(firstly for sending response secondly for throwing error)

Comment: Thank you. your one comment solved my problem. Actually, my code sending the JSON response twice that why it is giving me an error. Now everything is perfect.